# Copy Paste Powershell Excel Keep Formatting

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to automate the process of copying and pasting data but it is important for me to keep the formatting of the cells the same.

I have tried using `PasteSpecial(-4163)` but that has not worked. Strangely enough it turned some values Bold and other values it un-bold (?).

Here is the function I created to carry out the copying and pasting. 
Anybody have any suggestions?

```
function CopyPasteRange
{
    #args[0] = sheet
    #args[1] = row
    #args[2] = column

    $range = $args[0].Cells.Item($args[1], ($args[2])).EntireColumn;
    $range.Copy();
    $args[0].Cells.Item(1, $args[2]).PasteSpecial(-4163);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution! I deleted the -4163 value in `PasteSpecial(-4163)` and now that copies the cells with formatting and everything.

I feel super special!

Comment: [MSDN info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx). `-4163` is paste values, `-4122` is paste with formatting

Comment: You had originally used the xlPasteValues parameter. Did you want to retain formulas?

Comment: Ah that explains it! I was never sure of what that integer was doing. Mind...blown. Cheers guys. Nah no formulas. What the program is going to do is run SQL queries to get data into a CSV. Then, previous weeks book opened and prepped for new data (i.e. copy paste previous formatted data). Data from queries will be created into lookup tables, copy results into new created formatted cells and bam done!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Range.PasteSpecial method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx)'s [XlPasteType enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx) you are currently pasting values (e.g. `xlPasteValues`). You will have to run a second PasteSpecial operation using something like **13** (`xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme`) as the XlPasteType  parameter.

```
function CopyPasteRange
{
    #args[0] = sheet
    #args[1] = row
    #args[2] = column

    $range = $args[0].Cells.Item($args[1], ($args[2])).EntireColumn;
    $range.Copy();
    $args[0].Cells.Item(1, $args[2]).PasteSpecial(-4163);
    $args[0].Cells.Item(1, $args[2]).PasteSpecial(13);
}
```

Comment: That would be kind of redundand to do 2 pastes no? Just use the correct `xl` value otherwise its just more work? But your explanation helped me understand what I did wrong though :)

Comment: There will be times when you will want to specifically copy the values returned by formulas and not the formulas themselves. Unfortunately, you cannot add the two parameters together like `, xlPasteValues + xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme` like you can with some more-bitwise parameters. If a Copy and Paste is all that is required, then PasteSpecial isn't even needed as the [Range.Copy method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760.aspx) has an optional destination parameter of its own.