# Copy CSV Rows to an Existing Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, powershell

This should be pretty simple.  I'm looking to take the information from [my previous question(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223646/calculate-time-from-document), which is a CSV, and place them in an existing Excel document.

Here's the existing data (in a CSV):

```
    SO       |    Status     |    ElapsedHrs
PMTT12345678    Hit on Debra          2.5
PMTS23456789    Get rejected          4.25
PMTT87654321   Send some faxes        1.0
```

So I have an existing Excel sheet, where all of the `SO` category needs to go to column K starting at cell 6, `Status` goes to L starting at 6 and `ElapsedHrs` goes to column O starting at cell 6.

[Using this](https://gregcaporale.wordpress.com/2016/08/26/powershell-to-copy-data-from-csv-to-excel/) and a few others as examples, but I can't figure out the syntax.  Any help is appreciated, again.

## Edit

So far I have this:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Excel.visible = $false
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($ExportCsv)
$WorkBook2 = $excel.Workbooks.open($Template)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item(“$ExpCsvShort”)
```

`$ExportCsv` is the name of the CSV with the full path.  `$ExpCsvShort' is just the filename (the name changes based on the hour and date).`  $Template` is the template .xslx file to which the data would be written.

```
$range = $WorkSheet.Range(“A2”).EntireColumn
$range.Copy() | out-null
```

Not sure what this should be, as I want column `A` (minus the header) to go to K on $Template starting at 6.  Then I want `C` to start at L6 and `D` to start at O6, but I don't know the syntax.

Once I have that:

```
$Worksheet2 = $Workbook2.Worksheets.item(“Worklog”)
$worksheet2.activate()
$range2 = $Worksheet2.Range(“K6:K6”)
$Worksheet2.Paste($range2)
$workbook2.SaveAs($WorkLogSave)
$workbook.close($false)
$Excel.Quit()
 [gc]::collect()
 [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

But again, I don't know the syntax for the range here, either.

## Edit 2

Here's what I ended up doing.

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Excel.visible = $true
$WorkBook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($ExportCsv)
$WorkBook2 = $excel.Workbooks.open($Template)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item($ExpCsvShort)
$Worksheet.activate()
#A Range Copy
$rangeAc = $WorkSheet.Range(“A2:A26”)
$rangeAc.Copy() | out-null
#Select sheet 2
$Worksheet2 = $Workbook2.Worksheets.item(“Worklog”)
$worksheet2.activate()
#A Range Paste
$rangeAp = $Worksheet2.Range(“K6:K30”)
$Worksheet2.Paste($rangeAp)
#C Range Copy
$rangeCc = $WorkSheet.Range(“C2:C26”)
$rangeCc.Copy() | out-null
#C Range Paste
$rangeCp = $Worksheet2.Range(“O6:O30”)
$Worksheet2.Paste($rangeCp)
#D Range Copy
$rangeDc = $WorkSheet.Range(“D2:D26”)
$rangeDc.Copy() | out-null
#D Range Paste
$rangeDp = $Worksheet2.Range(“L6:L30”)
$Worksheet2.Paste($rangeDp)

$workbook2.SaveAs($WorkLogSave)
$workbook2.close($true)
$workbook.close($true)
$Excel.Quit()
 [gc]::collect()
 [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Probably a pretty crappy way to do it, but it works.  Also, I still have EXCEL.EXE running after everything is closed.  I've read about 5 ways to kill the process, but I'm worried if I do I'll mess someone up who has another document open, so maybe I can `-passthru` and capture the `.id` and kill that instead, but I'll worry about that later I guess.

Thanks for helping, all.

And I'd love to use that gravity, but I'm not sure I understand how.  Thanks!

Comment: Let's say your existing data is on "Sheet1". Could you not just do a formula, starting in `K6` of your new sheet? `=Sheet1!A2`?

Comment: The data is in a CSV being created from another script.  They aren't in the same document, but thanks.  I'm looking to pull data from the CSV.  I should probably specify.

Comment: The idea is the same, even if they're not the same document. With your CSV open, in your separate Excel worksheet, you can type `=` into Cell `K6`, then click the cell in the CSV you want the value of.

Comment: If you're wanting to script it using PowerShell, as well, it's also fairly straightforward if you follow like the example you linked in the question.  Can you show what you wrote in PowerShell, and what error you're getting, specifically?

Comment: @gravity there's what I have so far.

Comment: You know, one of the easiest ways to see what's happening is to manually execute the lines of code, and also specify `$Excel.Visible = $true`.  Then you can see exactly what your code is doing.

Comment: `.Range("K6", "K7")` would be a *"selection of cells"* but you've got K6 listed twice... if you're trying to determine the 'end cell' to paste to (the second range parameter), you probably want to set a variable to `UsedRange.Rows` or something akin to that.

Comment: @BaconBits I'm aware, thanks.  That's how I knew the script worked up to right after I opened the document to make edits.  :)

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is this:  how do I tell PowerShell to take the data in the CSV Column A starting at A2 and paste it into the Excel sheet Column K starting at K6?

Comment: How do you know that row 2 of the CSV matches up to row 6 of the Excel sheet?  Is there a shared column between the two data files, or is it purely based on the fact that they've magically been set up correctly?

Comment: I'm thinking for the range you need to use `$range = $WorkSheet.Range(“A2:A1048572”)`  Then for the destination range you can use `$range2 = $Worksheet2.Range(“K6:K1048576”)`.  Repeat for the remaining columns.  That's assuming its an .xlsx file.

Comment: @BaconBits thanks, but that's just how these match.  I'm trying to pull data from a sheet and autofill it so I don't have to do it by hand.  A on CSV matches K on Excel, C to L and D to O, all at 6.  I have some of it figured out already.  I really just need to know how to get rid of the first line, but select the rest of the document.  If I have to, I'll just cut the header out.

Comment: Again, you really should be looking at `UsedRange.Rows` and that will give you an `int` to tell you the *last row.*  From there, you know what that second parameter's number should be, akin to `"K6:K" + $iRowsCounted`

Comment: @gravity thanks I'll need to read up and learn as yours would definitely be superior.  I'm also trying to figure out if I can somehow preserve the cell formatting while I add this data to the existing Excel document, since I lose the cell colors and borders when I paste information over them.

Comment: @Nate - Yes, that's what [`.PasteSpecial()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782659/copy-paste-powershell-excel-keep-formatting) is used for.  There are unique numbers best used in PowerShell as constant type variables/objects.  Per that link (in the code), you should use `-4122` as your `PasteSpecial` parameter.

Comment: [Here are all the values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx)

Comment: If you aren't familiar with a term (ala, `PasteSpecial`, or `UsedRange`, for example) you should be using Google to find documentation to try and implement it yourself some first.  Quickly googling "powershell usedrange rows" gives me several immediate results.  Like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937788/get-the-number-of-rows-in-column-of-a-worksheet) StackOverflow question/answer.

Comment: @gravity Wow, thanks!  If I can ask one more question about this:  where can I find the syntax for this?  On which line of code do I append the .PasteSpecial(-4122)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130978/discussion-between-gravity-and-nate).