# PowerShell Paste To Excel - Match Destination

Tags: excel, powershell

Per my [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226955/copy-csv-rows-to-an-existing-excel-sheet), I'd now like have my data in my Excel sheet retain the Excel sheet's current formatting.  Basically the Excel sheet has a background color and specific borders already set for cells.  When I copy my data to the cells with:

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Excel.visible = $true
$WorkBook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($ExportCsv)
$WorkBook2 = $excel.Workbooks.open($Template)
$Worksheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item($ExpCsvShort)
$Worksheet.activate()
#A Range Copy
$rangeAc = $WorkSheet.Range(“A2:A26”)
$rangeAc.Copy() | out-null
#Select sheet 2
$Worksheet2 = $Workbook2.Worksheets.item(“Worklog”)
$worksheet2.activate()
#A Range Paste
$rangeAp = $Worksheet2.Range(“K6:K30”)
$Worksheet2.Paste($rangeAp)
#C Range Copy
$rangeCc = $WorkSheet.Range(“C2:C26”)
$rangeCc.Copy() | out-null
#C Range Paste
$rangeCp = $Worksheet2.Range(“O6:O30”)
$Worksheet2.Paste($rangeCp)
#D Range Copy
$rangeDc = $WorkSheet.Range(“D2:D26”)
$rangeDc.Copy() | out-null
#D Range Paste
$rangeDp = $Worksheet2.Range(“L6:L30”)
$Worksheet2.Paste($rangeDp)
```

I lose the formatting on the cells.  I saw [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782659/copy-paste-powershell-excel-keep-formatting) and tried the `.PasteSpecial()` method, which failed (can't call on a null expression) but the data still came over.

Is there a way to preserve my cell background colors and borders when I paste my data without completely rewriting my script?  Is there a location I can add the `.PasteSpecial()` in my existing code to match destination formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I was thinking my line should be:

```
$rangeAp = $Worksheet2.Range(“K6:K30”)
$Worksheet2.PasteSpecial(-4163, $rangeAp)
```

But it should be:

```
$rangeAp = $Worksheet2.Range(“K6:K30”)
$rangeAp.PasteSpecial(-4163)
```

I misunderstood how to invoke the `.PasteSpecial()`.  I hope you guys are smarter than me on this!